# How to unit test a method which calls Response.AppendToLog?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, httpcontext

I am writing a public function which writes data into `HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendToLog` is there any way to write Unit test for this?

I tried creating mock/custom object of `HttpContext` and assigned to `HttpContext.Current` but how to assert the data written by AppendToLog.

Answer (score 3):

Make an interface and wrap HttpContext with an implementation.

```
public interface IHttpContext
{
    void AppendToResponseLog(/*parmas go here*/);
}

public class HttpContextWrapper : IHttpContext
{
    private HttpContext _httpContext = HttpContext.Current; //or constructor param


    public void AppendToResponseLog(/*parmas go here*/)
    {
        _httpContext.Response.AppendToLog(/*params*/);
    }  
}
```

Now make your class dependent on `IHttpContext` instead of `HttpContext.Current`.  As far as testing, you can now mock `IHttpContext`.

Note: Use this same method for all .NET Framework dependencies you want to be able to test/mock.